# Having trouble with input in for loop with error message. [input expected at most 1 argument, got 3]

Tags: python

I'm having trouble with a for loop that is going to ask for an assignment score and a max score that could have been achieved. But I'm getting the following error message [input expected at most 1 argument, got 3]

I kind of understand what that means but, how do I go about getting the results of the following screenshot below? I'm just focused on getting the error message resolved. Also in getting for loop to execute properly.

[image]

Here is the code that I have so far

```
#defing funtion for homeowrk
def homeWork():

    #Asking user for weight of assignment
    weight = int(input("Weight (0-100)? "))

    #Ask user for number of assignments will determine how many times the question will run
    numberOfAssignment = int(input("Number of assignments? "))

    #if statment that will execute dependant on user input
    for i in range(numberOfAssignment):

        #prompt user for assignment score
        assignmentScore = int(input("Assignment", i + 1 ,"max?"))

        # prompt user for assignment optiential score
        maxScore = int(input("Assignment", i + 1 ,"max? "))

#calling funtion
homeWork()
```

Comment: Read [tour] and [ask]. You should replace your picture of text with the *actual text*. And please edit into your question the **full** text of the error message, as text, so it’s possible to see which line gives the error message, and the call stack that got there.

Answer (score 1):

Input is not like print: you have to do the string munging yourself.  Instead of

```
input("this", "that", 8)
```

You want

```
input(f"this that {8}")
```

Comment: WOW that worked, I'm not seeing that in the book I'm reading but I'll take it!

Comment: This is actually the norm: taking n arguments and joining them together is only done in a few built in functions, for convenience